# Is there any mention to someone wearing tefillin in Tanach?

Tags: history, tanach, tefilin

Aside from the passages in Shmah, are there any accounts discussing or of Jews wearing tefillin in tanach?

Comment: Many mitzvos aren't mentioned . An omission of a mitzvah is not a proof that they weren't observed, rather it was taken for granted that they did them. However, things that they struggled with were mentioned.  Indeed shabbos is something that is mentioned...

Comment: This system (of closing duplicative questions) seems to leave no place for this comment: the old question to which we're re-directed never really got an answer either. That question was why tefillin are not mentioned in Nach, and I don't see how the answer there is in fact an answer at all. Like Sam's comment here, it seems to assume an argumentative agenda in the question (maybe they didn't wear tefillin at all, or maybe they didn't wear them all day, or something like this) and respond to this imaginary question in stead of the one actually asked.

Comment: If Nach mentions people eating and sleeping and dressing and fighting and conversing and so on, why doesn't it mention people wearing tefillin?

Answer (score 2):

[Yechezkel 24:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.17?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he). Yechezkel is told by G-d not to observe the usual signs of mourning for the death of his wife. Instead, among other things (and unlike regular mourners), he should keep his Pe'er tied on him (פְּאֵֽרְךָ֙ חֲב֣וֹשׁ עָלֶ֔יךָ). Rashi says that is referring to Tefillin.